# How to Link to a record in Lightning using Apex

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

I am sending an email notification to internal users from the community through Apex SingleEmailMessage when a partner user posts in Chatter Feed. I wanted to add a link to the Opportunity record into the email. I've tried this which I've also found in other posts:

```
String Recordlink = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+opp.Id;

mail.setHtmlBody(' Link: ' + Recordlink);
```

..but it doesn't seem to work for me, I am redirected to an error page saying the portal is down when I click on the link.

The generated link is:
Link: https://**sandboxname-orgname**.cs123.force.com/0060K00000Zwq7NQAR

I noticed that when I open an opportunity in the system, the link is a bit different.
https://**orgname--sandboxname**.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Opportunity/0060K00000Zwq7NQAR/view

Is there a different way of adding the link for lightning? Thanks!

Comment: Oops, I discovered it after few minutes of posting this question. I'm not sure how to delete this post but just I just found out I have to use getOrgDomainUrl() instead of  getSalesforceBaseUrl()

Comment: You can post this as answer and then mark your own answer as having solved the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String Recordlink = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+opp.Id;